# Getting Error 401 on CORS Request from Frontend to Java Spring Boot Backend

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, react-native, cors

I have a frontend with **React-Native** (0.55.1; localhost:8080) and a backend with **Java 8 Spring Boot** (2.0.2; localhost: 8081) with Spring Web Security. I want to do a post request from the frontend to the backend to POST some data. Since this should be a CORS Request, I need to config my backend to allow handling CORS-Requests. This is what I tried (see below), but I keep getting a 401 ("Unauthorized"), if I post a request to the Spring Boot Server. This is my Config for backend:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    // turn off checking for CSRF tokens
    http.csrf().disable();

    http
            .cors()
            .and()
          .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll() // **permit OPTIONS call to all**
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
            .and()
          .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/api/login")
            .usernameParameter("userName")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
          .logout().logoutUrl("/api/logout");

    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((req, res, exc) -> res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED));

    http.formLogin().successHandler((req, res, auth) -> clearAuthenticationAttributes(req));

    http.formLogin().failureHandler((req, res, exc) -> res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED));

    http.logout().logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler());
    }

@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
   CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
   configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:8081"));
   configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE"));
   configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
   configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
   UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
   source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/**", configuration);
   return source;
  }
```

I do the call (a POST) from the frontend with Axios (via apisauce: https://github.com/infinitered/apisauce) from a React client 
 on localhost:8081:

```
import apisauce from 'apisauce'
const create = (baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/api/') => {
const api = apisauce.create({baseURL,
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      "Content-type": "application/json",
    },
    withCredentials: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    // 10 second timeout...
    timeout: 10000
    })

 // this is the Axios POST request with apisauce 
 api.post('login', data)
```

How can I achieve a successfull request?

Comment: I guess try removing `.authorizeRequests()` and `.anyRequest().authenticated()` and whatever else that code has which is causing authentication to be required for requests.

Comment: I tried disabling all that but it doesn't work :)